# get the entity via key string , google app engine ndb(datastore)

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am using google app engine with python. the server got the entity key from the user, then I use this code to bring the entity:

```
 key.get()
```

but I also want to get the entity just if it related to particular model, How could I do that ?
I know that I could do that by this code:

```
MyModel.get_by_id('my_key')
```

but this works just for the key_name and the id , and in my case I use the key ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After getting user-provided key as urlsafe string from server, construct the NDB key, e.g.:

```
key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=string)
```

I'm not sure though, why you don't simply use `key.get()` after importing `MyModel` :-)

However, this is how you get an instance using its ID (whether string or integer):

```
MyModel.get_by_id(key.id(), parent=key.parent(), app=key.app(), namespace=key.namespace())
```

The keywords are optional, unless you use multiple namespaces or application IDs, or MyModel is child class in an entity group.

Alternatively, use `key.string_id()` or `key.integer_id()`

Security warning: Since your app accepts user-provided keys, be aware that even the cryptically looking URL-safe keys can be easily encoded/decoded.

For details see [Reference for NDB Key](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Key_id)

Comment: thank you very much, so I should write : key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=key_string) and then get the entity by MyModel.get_by_id(key.id()) and not by key.get(), excuse me actually I don't understand your warning , do you mean that i should get the id (not the key) from the user? :) thank you

Comment: You should prefer using key.get() if you always want to lookup the key. The benefit to using `MyModel.get_by_id` is that it will always get a model of type `MyModel`. However, if you want to always get the given `key` if it is of type `MyModel`, you could get the kind of your key by calling `key.kind()` and compare it to `'MyModel'`, then call `get()` if that is true.

Comment: I agree with Patrick on the preferred use of `key.get()`. There are rather exotic cases, where `MyModel.get_by_id()` makes more sense. My security warning goes both ways: Everyone can take the URL-safe key and decode it. So if your app has sensitive data as IDs or key-names, for example `Key("Email", "me@example.com")`, the email address would also be exposed. Also, once users figure out the pattern of your keys (and the underlying datastore model), they could come up with their own keys, e.g. `Key("Email", "friend@example.com")` and try if your app will expose whether such entity exists.